# How to connect Active Reports 7 to use a stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, activereports

How to connect Active Reports 7 to use a stored procedures? I have stored procedures already written, but how do you connect to them to use the data in the tables so that my report is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveReports 7 has two different report types, with slightly different ways of using stored procedures.

If you are using a SectionReport (i.e. the traditional form of report that was available in ActiveReports 6) then you can execute a stored procedure via the EXEC SQL command in your query.  f.e.

`EXEC sp_mysp '<%myparameter%>'`

In a PageReport (i.e. the new report type introduced in ActiveReports 7) then you need to set the command type to Stored Procedure and then the query string is set to the name of your stored procedure.  If you have any parameters to pass then you can pass them in via the DataSet's parameters page.

In PageReports when working with the ADO.NET based data providers (SQL Server, OLE DB, and Oracle connection types) there is a 1-to-1 correlation between objects in the data source, data set, and parameters in Page Reports and what you see in the related ADO.NET *Connection, *Command, and *Parameter classes.  So if you have questions about how those work you can just look at how you would write the same code with the ADO.NET classes.